# Create a new table and adding a data from old one in SQL Server 2017 in one query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a main table that contains all cities and regions in Switzerland.

[image]

I want to create a table for each city, and copy the city data directly from the main to the new one according to its abbreviation.

For example, create a table for Zurich and copy all data from the old table when the abbreviation is ZH.
create a table for Schaffhausen and copy all data from the old table when the abbreviation is SH.

I've used the following query, but did not work:

```
CREATE TABLE Zurich AS SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Post Code]
WHERE abbreviation = 'ZH'
```

Comment: You may use `select into` in sql server, but simply cloning the table will lose the structure, you should clone the structure first, then inserting the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, I found the solution.

```
USE [Post Code];  
GO  
CREATE TABLE dbo.Zurich  
( PostCode   int,  
  Place nvarchar(25),
  Canton nvarchar(50)  ,
  Abbreviation nvarchar(2),
  Country nvarchar(11)
);  
GO  
INSERT INTO dbo.Zurich  
    SELECT *   
    FROM [dbo].[Post Code] WHERE Abbreviation = 'ZH';  
GO
```

[image]

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/copy-columns-from-one-table-to-another-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Below, what I have answered also do the same thing, I think you haven't tried it.

Comment: Even if it works it is wrong. 1) Do not create tables, create Views (`create view dbo.Zurich as select * from dbo.[post code] where abbreviation='ZH'`) and use `dbo.Zurich` as though it were a table. 2) Postal codes, even if they consist of digits are **not** numbers (the same holds for phone numbers)

Answer (score 1):

As you are saying, you wan to create table and it's data based on `abbreviation` so you should use abbreviation instead of `Canton` and you should us `INTO` in `SQLSERVER`. You can use `CREATE TABLE <table_name> AS` in `MYSQL` and other databases

```
SELECT * INTO Zurich FROM [dbo].[Post Code]
WHERE Abbreviation = 'ZH'
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, I have a mistake in the question I corrected
But yes, that's exactly what I want, but unfortunately it does not work
look hier : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QyGvSvSM5GrvQ4dezmzvjvMqaWdBkq1z/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Yes, it will resolve that issue also and create table `Zurich` and insert all the available data `WHERE Abbreviation = 'ZH'`