# SQL- Create table does not work in SQL Server Management Studio SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server

For some reason I can't create a new table from an another in SSMS.

```
use master;

create table bop as
select *
from dbo.Data$
where [2016] is not null and 
      [Series Name] = 'Imports of goods and services (% of GDP)' or 
      [Series Name] = 'Exports of goods and services (% of GDP)'
order by [Country Name] asc;
```

It outputs the error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4 
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.

Anybody experienced this problem before? I'm thinking its a bug

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a new table and adding a data from old one in SQL Server 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51737348/create-a-new-table-and-adding-a-data-from-old-one-in-sql-server-2017)

Comment: Where [in the SQL Server manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-reference?view=sql-server-2017) did you find that syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below way

```
SELECT * INTO schema.newtable FROM schema.oldtable WHERE 1 = 0
```

From your query you have to remove

```
create table bop as  ## this portion
```

and instead of it you have to add `select * INTO bop`

So your query will be

```
select * INTO bop
from dbo.Data$
where [2016] is not null and 
    (  [Series Name] = 'Imports of goods and services (% of GDP)' or 
      [Series Name] = 'Exports of goods and services (% of GDP)'
    )
order by [Country Name]
```

Instead of `OR` you can use `in` operator

```
select * INTO bop
    from dbo.Data$
    where [2016] is not null and 
          [Series Name] in ('Imports of goods and services (% of GDP)',
           'Exports of goods and services (% of GDP)')
    order by [Country Name]
```

Your Error analysis

- Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
  'select'.

As you used wrong sql statement to create one table from others table thats why sqlserver thrown systax Error

Comment: Where would the bop table be saved? It is not in the tables folder within the 'master' database

Comment: you can specify the database name

Comment: but default it will crate on selected database your query editor

Answer (score 1):

That is invalid `SQL` syntax for SQL Server  :

Instead you can do :

```
select d.* into bop
from dbo.Data$ d
where [2016] is not null and 
      [Series Name] in ('Imports of goods and services (% of GDP)', 'Exports of goods and services (% of GDP)')
order by [Country Name] asc;
```

Note :

- Use `IN` clause if you have a more than one constant values that is easier read & write.
- `OR` evaluates constant values one by one with no particular order, while `IN` sorts the list. So, `IN` is faster in some circumstances.
- `OR` will not include `null`s values if you have, but `IN` will include `null`. So, choose one of them based on what actually you want.

Comment: You should point out the logic change by using `in` (which is probably what the OP intends).

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues with your query.  The correct syntax for what you intend is:

```
select d.*
into bop
from dbo.Data$ d
where [2016] is not null and 
      [Series Name] in ('Imports of goods and services (% of GDP)', 'Exports of goods and services (% of GDP)');
```

Note the following:

- SQL Server uses `select into`, not `create table as`.  This is your basic syntax error.
- Presumably, you want either series name *and* `20161 not to be`NULL`.`in`does this.`AND`has higher precedence than`OR`, so your logic does something different.
- `ORDER BY` is not appropriate, unless the destination table has an identity column.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  The only ordering would be on the values in the `identity` column.